# Function not stopping after handleComplete

Tags: swift, google-places-api

I created a basic Google Places app that lets users check-in to a location. When a user tries to check in, I loop through the list of likelihood places to verify that the user is actually at the location in the app. However, when I try to escape the loop after confirming the location is correct, my function still ends up going to my "else" situation (an error message that asks the user to please check in to the correct location).

The following function gets called in viewWillAppear:

```
func checkIn(handleComplete:@escaping (()->())){

        guard let currentUserID = User.current?.key else {return}

        // Specify the place data types to return.
        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
            UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
        placesClient.findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation(withPlaceFields: fields, callback: {
            (placeLikelihoodList: Array<GMSPlaceLikelihood>?, error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList {
                    let place = likelihood.place
                    if likelihood.likelihood >= 0.75 && place.placeID! == self.hangoutID {
                        let place = likelihood.place
                        print("Current Place name \(String(describing: place.name!)) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                        print("Current PlaceID \(String(describing: place.placeID!))")

                        self.delta = 0.0

                        // update checkin
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let hangoutRef = self.db.collection("users").document(currentUserID).collection("hangout").document(self.hangoutID).updateData([
                                "lastCheckin": Date()
                            ]) { err in
                                if let err = err {
                                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Document successfully updated")
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        handleComplete()
                    }
                }
                self.presentDismissableAlert(title: "", message: "Please check in to the hangout to join this chat", button: "OK", dismissed: { (UIAlertAction) in
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToChats", sender: self)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

If the correct conditions are met, the code will land on the handleComplete() line but then it will still execute the dismissableAlert underneath and segue the user out of the room. How can I fix the flow so that the app will cycle through the list of likely Places and stop the function on handleComplete if the correct condition is met, or else then proceed to the error message if the correct conditions are not met (user is not at the correct Place)?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you expecting no further code to run after calling `handleComplete()`? It just another line of code line any other. Call `return` to skip the rest of the block contents.

Comment: ugh. I had a `return` call but it was one block deeper and didn't work. I guess this whole time all I needed to do was bump it up one level. Thanks for the straightforward answer I needed lol